# How can I set variable annotated with @Transient form a setter of non transient variable in spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to set the time variable while the Date and Time variable is getting initialized by spring JPA but I am getting null in the time string.
How should I approach this problem ?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cap_ratio")
public class CapacitiveInfoModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "time")
    private Date dateAndTime;
    @Transient
    private String time;

    public Date getDateAndTime() {
        return dateAndTime;
    }
    public void setDateAndTime(Date dateAndTime) {
        this.dateAndTime = dateAndTime;
        this.time = DateAndTimeUtil.getFormattedDateAndTimeString(dateAndTime, "HH:mm");
    }
    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is also here: https://solveforums.msomimaktaba.com/threads/solved-how-can-i-set-variable-annotated-with-transient-form-a-setter-of-non-transient-variable-in-spring-jpa.822604/#post-822936 I don’t know why it’s marked “solved” there because I don’t see any solution. Maybe it’s just me.

Comment: Probably your `getFormattedDateAndTimeString` method returns `null`. You may want to paste that method into your question.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. For a time of day use `LocalTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cap_ratio")
public class CapacitiveInfoModel {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "time")
    private Date dateAndTime;
    @Transient
    private String time;

    public Date getDateAndTime() {
        return dateAndTime;
    }
    public void setDateAndTime(Date dateAndTime) {
        this.dateAndTime = dateAndTime;
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        this.time = dateFormat.format(this.dateAndTime);
    }
    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }
}
```